# numbers independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ but not BA? numbers that aren't a basis for a number field but are BA?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-approximation

Has anyone discovered a vector of algebraic real numbers $(a_1,...,a_k)$ such that $1,a_1,...,a_k$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and such that $(a_1,...,a_k)$ is **not** "badly approximable"?

Has anyone discovered a vector of algebraic real numbers $(a_1,...,a_k)$ such that $$[\mathbb{Q}(a_1,...,a_k):\mathbb{Q}]>k+1$$ but such that $(a_1,...,a_k)$  **is** "badly approximable"?

knowing whether either of these is open would be a great help.

By badly approximable I mean that there exists $c>0$ such that the $\ell_\infty$ distance from $(qa_1,...,qa_k)$ to $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is greater than $cq^{-1/k}$ for all large $q\in \mathbb{N}$.

Or the equivalent notion that there exists $c>0$ such that the distance from $\sum_i q_i a_i$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is greater than $c\|q\|_{\ell_\infty}^{-k}$ for all large $q\in \mathbb{Z}^k$.

Comment: There are multiple notions of "badly approximable"; what definition are you considering?

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks I'ved edited the question

Comment: It would help in understanding the question if you could clarify what it says when $k=1$ and how it relates to Roth's theorem on approximation of algebraics.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Yes, I should have mentioned that  when k=1, the first question seems to be open: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177481/is-any-particular-algebraic-number-known-to-have-unbounded-continued-fraction-co.  So if I had to guess, I would assume that the k>1 case is open too, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen  Roth's theorem says that algebraic numbers are not "very well approximable".  Being badly approximable is stronger than being not very well approximable