# Does there exist a sequence $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $|\alpha x - y| \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ approaches a given real number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha > 0$ be a real irrational algebraic number and $c > 0$.
I am interested in the following question.
Does there exist a sequence $(x_i,y_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that
$$
\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} |\alpha x_i - y_i| \sqrt{x_i^2  + y_i^2} = c. 
$$
Maybe it's possible to prove otherwise, but it is not too clear to me what to expect.
Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You are asking for numbers with finite Markov constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_constant). This holds iff $\alpha$ is a quadratic irrational.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have not encountered this concept before. What exactly happens if $\alpha$ is not quadratic?

Comment: actually I'm not quite seeing how the finite Markov constant implies the answer to my question... could you possibly provide more details as an answer please?

Comment: @JohnnyT. , as you want to minimize the absolute value, you have $x_{i}\approx y_{i} $, hence one may replace the sqrt by $y_{i}$ (or $x_{i}$). This naive observation shows that if a number has a finite Markov constant, this holds. I am not sure what irreducible means here.

This question in general is very hard, as such an estimate would give an effective bound over the (finitely many) rationals in Roth's theorem...

Comment: @Asaf it was supposed to be irrational. It's fixed now thank you. Could you please clarify "what" holds if a number has a finite Markov constant in your comment?

Comment: Your claim holds (with c being maybe the Markov constant over sqrt2 or so)

Comment: @Asaf I see, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @KevinCasto not iff $\alpha$ is a quadratic irrational, but iff elements of a continued fraction of $\alpha$ are bounded, that is much weaker property.

Comment: Though the Markov constant is indeed quite related, it does't exactly answer OP's question, does it? What's been shown so far is "there exists such a sequence for some $c$ iff $\alpha$ has finite Markov constant," but this is different from knowing for what pairs $(\alpha, c)$ such a sequence exists. I guess you'd need to (a) characterize the set of Markov constants and (b) know when there exists such a sequence if $c$ is greater than the the inverse of the Markov constant of $\alpha$ (then it's not precluded by definition, but that's not a proof of existence...)

Answer (score 3):

First note that for all $(x,y)$ with $y/x$ sufficiently close to $\alpha$, we will have $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ very close to $|x|\sqrt{1 + \alpha^2}$. So we might as well scale $c$ by $\sqrt{1 + \alpha^2}$ and ask whether there are infinitely many $(x_i, y_i)$ with
$$ \lim_{i \to \infty} |\alpha x_i - y_i| |x_i| = \lim_{i \to \infty} \left|\alpha - \frac{y_i}{x_i}\right| |x_i|^2 = c$$
This is exactly the definition of the Markov constant of $\alpha$ being $1/c$. As Fedor Petrov said in the comments, the Markov constant is finite iff the continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$ is bounded, which is true in particular if $\alpha$ is a quadratic irrational (sorry for my original mistake).

Note that among *algebraic* numbers, it seems to be suspected that anything above degree 2 has unbounded continued fraction expansion, but this is totally unproven; see e.g. [Is any particular algebraic number known to have unbounded continued fraction coefficients?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177481/is-any-particular-algebraic-number-known-to-have-unbounded-continued-fraction-co)

Comment: The definition of Markov constant $m$ is if the $\liminf$ of that expression over all fractions $y/x$, which means that you can always achieve the value $1/m$, but a priori it could also be that we can also achieve values larger than $1/m$. Can we characterize somehow which values are achievable? I suppose hoping that any $c\in[1/m,\infty)$ is achievable is too naive of an expectation.